# How to make a NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate to check for NULL values?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, appkit, nspredicateeditor

I want to have an option in my NSPredicateEditor, preferable in the same dropdown as the other NSComparisonPredicate operators, that let users search for NULL values on a particular key path / field.

How do I do that?

I have tried everything, using a code based approach, except building a custom NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate class. Maybe that's the only solution, but that seems a bit of overkil for such simple feature.

Comment: Did you try anything, like creating the row template in code?

Comment: @Willeke: I only use a code based approach because my editor is dynamically filled. I tried everything except building a custom NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate class. Maybe that's the only solution, but that seems a bit of overkil for such standard feature.

Comment: Usually users don't know the difference between "" and NULL. `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` is  limited to “pop-up-pop-up-pop-up” and “pop-up-pop-up-view”. If you want "pop-up-pop-up" then you have to create a custom class.